# Как получить http-заголовок ответа локального сервера?

Tags: apache, веб-программирование, веб-сервер

Умные люди, подскажите пожалуйста, как бы получить http-заголовок ответа локального сервера? Понятно, что для получения ответа удаленного сервера можно использовать "яндекс-вебмастер", но для сервера, поднятого на рабочей машине, такая штука не годится. Может есть какой-нибудь плагин для Firefox, который покажет заголовки, или какая-нибудь опция у Lunx, чтобы просмотреть код ответа??

Comment: wireshark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно получать и для отдельной страницы. Юзаем телнет

```
telnet www.you_site 80 (ну или другой порт)GET /first/second/file.php HTTP/1.0 <жмём ENTER>Host:www.you_site<жмём ENTER дважды>
```

Тут должен пойти ответ и потом соединение будет разорвано.

Comment: Да, так он тоже ответ возвращает, если успеть вписать путь после GET =)Хотя, почему то, возвращает код 400 для страницы, где должен быть 200.На самом деле, все равно, через сURL удобней оказалось.

Answer (score 1):

Под рукой не ни telnet (или аналога), ни локального сервера, поэтому ответ "умозрительный".

Попробуйте передать через

```
telnet localhost 80
```

http  запрос get или head

```
GET / HTTP/1.1илиHEAD / HTTP/1.1
```

насколько помню, после команды должна идти по крайней мере одна пустая строка '\r\n',поэтому убедитесь, что telnet настроен завершать строки парой '\r\n'

Comment: А можно как-то ей получать ответ для страницы сайта? Т.е. не просто для "сервера" типо: "test.ru", а "test.ru/first/second/file.php"? Насколько я понимаю, telnet на такое не рассчитана?

Comment: На самом деле, я уже извернулся через cURL библиотеку для PHP =><?php  if( $curl = curl_init() ) {    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,'http://test.ru/first/file.php');    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_NOBODY,true);    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HEADER,true);    var_dump(curl_exec($curl));    curl_close($curl);  }?>Но неужели нельзя как-то проще, через браузер это провернуть?...

Comment: Не совсем понял, что Вы имеете в виду.telnet просто пересылает вводимые Вами символы на host:port по tcp и выводит на консоль (текущее окно) текст, отправляемый сервером.Если "окно" позволяет, Вы можете делать Copy-Paste для сохранения ответов.

Comment: можно и через браузер, в частности через FF, только с установленным дополнением LiveHeader (так вроде называется) или подобным